# NuxtJS + BootstrapVue + TailwindCSS: Can I efficiently use Bootstrap Vue components but style with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am creating an app and using Tailwind CSS for most of the design. However, there are a couple of components from BootstrapVue that I would like to use.

Is it possible to import some of the components such as the [Form Tags component](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-tags) as a plugin ? If so, how can I optimize this so I can get the smallest file possible in NuxtJS? Would it be OK to perhaps use all of the BootstrapVue form components but style it with Tailwind CSS?

If you can provide an optimal method for tree shaking, importing, etc that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use shaking in `bootstrap-vue` in nuxt based on the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#transformasseturls-with-nuxtjs)

I used this method in my project in the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
bootstrapVue: {
    icons: false,
    componentPlugins: [
        'LayoutPlugin',
        'FormPlugin',
    ],
    components: ['BContainer', 'BRow', 'BCol' ],
    directives: ['VBModal', 'VBToggle', 'VBTooltip'],
},
```

Of course, you can put whatever you want in the config file.